# How to mock Object Mapper

Tags: testing, mocking, objectmapper, abp

abp.io framework - testing

I am trying to set an ApplicationService class.
The method I'm trying to test uses 'ObjectMapper.Map<classFrom, classTo>(obj)'

I have used NSubstitue as LazyServiceProvider, but I am unable to find the correct Substitute to create an ObjectMapper.

Has anyone done this?

Comment: Show the definition of your `ApplicationService` class and how you inject/instantiate it in your test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We resolved the issue.

We used a substitute for LazyServiceProvider.

Then the key was using a very specific setup when the LazyServiceProvider is trying to create the Object Mapper (see the abp code).

```
_abpProvider = Substitute.For<IAbpLazyServiceProvider>();
_abpProvider.LazyGetService<IObjectMapper>(Arg.Any<Func<IServiceProvider, object>>()).Returns(_objectMapper);
```

This allowed us to set up our own ObjectMapper in our test method, and have it be used in our ApplicationService.